# PyQt Drag and Drop - Nothing happens

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt

I'm trying to get drop a file onto a Window (I've tried the same thing with a QListWidget without success there too)

test.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# Test
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
from qt_test import Ui_MainWindow
class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.__class__.dragEnterEvent = self.DragEnterEvent
        self.__class__.dragMoveEvent = self.DragEnterEvent
        self.__class__.dropEvent = self.drop
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        print "Initialized"
        self.show()

    def DragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    def drop(self, event):
        link=event.mimeData().text()
        print link

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MyForm()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

And here's qt_test.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created: Thu May 20 12:23:19 2010
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.6
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        MainWindow.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

I've read [this email](http://www.mail-archive.com/pyqt@riverbankcomputing.com/msg12976.html) and I've followed everything said there. I still don't get any output except "Initialized" and the drag doesn't seem to get accepted (both for files from a file manager and plain text dragged from a text editor). Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: In my situation, I found that QListView requires reimplementation of dragMoveEvent, in addition to dragEnter and drop events. QListWidget only the latter two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Well... sort of.

Dragging plain text from an editor worked fine for me, as for files...

When you drop a file onto your app, it's type is `"text/uri-list"`. For this you will want to use the `event.mimeData().urls()` method to get a list of `PyQt4.QtCore.QUrl` objects.

You will need to handle different mime data formats differently.  You can use the following methods of the mimeData() to find out what attributes it has:

```
hasColor()
hasFormat()
hasHtml()
hasImage()
hasText()
hasUrls()
```

Comment: Dragging text doesn't work at all for me. The "+" mouse pointer doesn't appear, no text is printed in the terminal. Have you made any changes to the files provided?

Comment: Thanks! I managed to fix the problem. python-qt4 was migrated to squeeze yesterday so that seemed to have fixed it for me. I've accepted your answer because I  hadn't found anything about the .urls() method when looking up about this elsewhere, so you saved me some looking up.

Comment: I found the .urls() method by using `dir(event.mimeData())`.  If you aren't using windows, it might explain the differences in behavior.